# Linux C how to open a directory and get a file descriptor

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open("/home/zhangke", O_DIRECTORY | O_RDWR)) ==-1)
    {
        printf("error %s\n", strerror(errno));
       return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`/home/zhangke` **is** a directory and **it exists**. I get error `Is a directory`, so, how can I use `open()` to get a `fd` of a directory correctly?

Comment: Use `opendir()` to open a directory.

Comment: You can't read and write the raw data of a directory, you have to read it using `readdir()`.

Comment: Thank you! I want to get a file descriptor of a directory install of a point of DIR.

Comment: You can't get a file descriptor for a directory.

Comment: `openat()` and `mkdirat()`  need a file descriptor for a directory.

Comment: Actually, you can get an FD to a directory, but you get your error if you try to use `O_RDWR`. Use `O_RDONLY`.

Comment: `O_RDONLY` worked. Thank you!

Comment: If you use [`dir = opendir(...);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) to open a directory, you can use [`dirfd(dir)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirfd.3.html) to obtain the underlying descriptor. In Linux using 2.6.39, 3.x, 4.x, or later kernels, you can use [`open(dirpath, O_DIRECTORY | O_PATH)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) to obtain a file descriptor to the specified directory for use with fchdir() and *at() functions; but see the `O_PATH` notes on the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) for the other restrictions.

Comment: (The difference between `open(dirpath, O_DIRECTORY | O_PATH)` and  `open(dirpath, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY)` is that the latter will fail if you do not have (exec and) read access to the directory. The former requires only exec access.)

Comment: For those who might get curious about which flags glibc's `opendir` function uses, check out https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/opendir.c.html#opendir_oflags

tl;dr: `opendir_oflags = O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY|O_DIRECTORY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXE`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `O_RDONLY` instead of `O_RDWR` as the access mode. From the `open(2)` error list:

> `EISDIR` pathname refers to a directory and the access requested involved writing (that is, `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` is set).

As far as I can tell, there's no way to create and open a directory atomically. The `O_CREAT` flag always creates a regular file. `O_DIRECTORY` is only meaningful when opening an existing name, it checks that the name refers to a directory.

Comment: Note that using the O_CREAT flag in a directory will also fail with EISDIR.

Comment: Is there a way to create a directory and get an opened file descriptor for that directory in one call? (probably what passing `O_CREAT` should do)

Comment: I don't think so. What would you do with a descriptor referring to an empty directory? You can't open directories in write mode.

Comment: @Barmar: Same stuff you'd do with a path to an empty directory, but with `at` functions and less race conditions. Create files in it with `openat`, for example.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I guess the designers didn't think of that, because they didn't provide a way to create and open a directory atomically. Directories can only be created with `mkdir(2)`, and it doesn't open it.