# How can I open directory with open() function in C?

Tags: c, directory, fcntl

I want to open a directory without using <dirent.h>.
I tried this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd = open("dir", O_RDONLY, 0);
```

But it returns fd = -1. Why? As I know, the directory is a file too, it just stores the location of children files and directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154232/linux-c-how-to-open-a-directory-and-get-a-file-descriptor

Answer (score 0):

You can open directories with open, but what you probably want is the function `opendir`.

You will benefit from reading the manual page for open, especially the parts about `O_PATH` and `O_DIRECTORY`.

To learn the details of the directory reading ABI, read the source of opendir/readdir in your C library.

Comment: I know opendir() function. I'm just interested, how can I open a directory as a file?

Comment: why do people think a directory can be opened as a file? What do they expect to read from it? Some time ago a friend of mine asked the same because he used to launch "vim dir/" and he was able to read file list "as a file".. which of course is a vim feature

Comment: @Jack It /can/ be opened and read as a file, this is what happens inside readdir.  It just isn't something that most people should want to do.

Comment: @TomV In my system this returns -1 `read(open("/home", 0), buf, 10)`: `home` directory can't be read as file, even if the open() returns a valid file descriptor. What (and how) do you expect to read from it?